# Functions with Regex for validation OR HTML5 Validator

Tags: regex, html, validation

I've just discovered the HTML5 validator feature and I feel that it is really easy to use (and also very aesthetically pleasing, especially the red warning borders and the speech bubbles that show the required input format)!

However, I don't know if it is better to use functions with regex to manually check every user input, example:

```
    function check_title($title){
    if(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/", $title))
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
```

or to use the HTML5 validator, example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" maxlength="16" pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}" title="Username must be 5-16 length" required/>
```

May I know which one is more secure? Because I am trying to create a secure website.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Secure doesn't matter here.  Will it support all browser?

Comment: I think it is not supported in some browsers, especially browsers of earlier versions

Comment: No client side validation is secure. Use client side validation to improve the user experience, but all your validations should finally be done on server side.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. So does it mean I should use the HTML5 validator first, and then the validation functions to check it once more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTML5` though a latest rocking technology, yet it is still a work in progress.  **Older version of browser won't support it** (you can find some work around to support it).

If you support only latest browser, then `HTML5` will be good to use.  Being client-side, you can't find it secure, so think how you're presenting/supporting the site.

else go for `Regex`, because still most number of people are using older version.

Hope you know this

> [**HTML5Shiv**](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) is a JavaScript workaround, discovered by *Sjoerd Visscher*, to enable styling of HTML5 elements in versions of Internet
>   Explorer prior to version 9, which do not allow unknown elements to be
>   styled without JavaScript.

Just found this [**HTML5 Validation**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

> HTML5's constraint validation APIs make adding client side validation
>   to forms quick while providing a JavaScript API and CSS hooks for
>   customization.
>
> ***While there are still some issues with the implementations and old
>   browsers to deal with, with a good polyfill or server-side fallback
>   you can utilize these APIs in your forms today.***

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! would it be ok if I include both HTMl5 and Regex ?

Comment: I appreciate your eagerness for `HTML5`.   Though it will work, my suggestion will be go with HTML5 and use a work around solution to support HTML5 check this http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: wow, hey thanks for the links that you have provided! i really appreciate it. I will try them out :)

Comment: @bob I'm glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way is to verify the posted values server side. Never thrust a client!

Comment: so does it mean I should use the validation functions to check the user inputs instead of the HTML5 validator?

Comment: It means you should check the input server side. It's possible to do this client side as well, but you should also do it server side.